# Is it possible to implement custom transformers?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to implement custom [transformers](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/properties#transformers) to perform non-trivial transformations, preferably both ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, App Maker doesn't have a mechanism to add custom transformers.

However, you can use client scripts to transform your bindings. For example, if you have a label that bound to **@datasource.item.name**, you can create **Client Script** with a function:

```js
function nameTransformer(name) {
  return name + ' after transformation';
}
```

and change your binding to **nameTransformer(@datasource.item.name)**. That function can contain more complex logic.